# Is the character Johan Larsen supernatural?

Tags: character, 1864

In the TV show [1864](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1753353/), there is a character named Johan Larsen, portraited by Søren Malling. He does weird stuff throughout the show (magical/spiritual approach maybe). Is he some kind of saint or something, or represents abstract entity?

Comment: As far as I know, he’s simply meant to represent a kind of ‘guiding star’ to younger soldiers. He is supernatural in the sense that he’s psychic, a healer and able to manipulate and hypnotise people, but he’s not a saint or anything that extreme – just a person with some supernatural gifts. The real Johan Peter Larssen, of course, was nothing of the sort. His role as ‘guiding star’ came from the fact that he was older and had more experience in war than his fellows, and he gave them advice freely.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Would you consider the reply reposting as an answer?